Preprocessing data for regression: scale/normalize only joint observations, or regressor and regressand observations separately?
Suppose that you observe two variables $X, Y$ (regressor and regressand) that are statistically associated, $Y \sim X$.
Your data are iid samples $\mathcal{D}:=\{(x_j, y_j) \mid j=1,\ldots, N\}\subset \mathbb{R}^ {d_X}\!\!\times\!\mathbb{R}^{d_Y}$ of $(X,Y)$.
Then, you want to apply to this data some regression method, say kernel ridge regression or SVR.
For this, one is typically recommended to preprocess the data samples $(x_j)$ and $(y_j)$ by normalizing or standardizing them.
Question: Will such a standardization/normalization be applied to (subsets of) the joint observations $\{(x_j, y_j)\}$, or should the componental data $(x_j)$ and $(y_j)$ be scaled separately?
Since the association $Y\sim X$ be quite nonlinear (e.g. $Y = e^X + \varepsilon$ or similar), preprocessing $(x_j)$ and $(y_j)$ separately seems problematic, since applying different ($(x_j)$- resp. $(y_j)$-dependent) scales to regressand and regressor samples, respectively, might non-trivially interfere with the statistical association $Y\sim X$.
Happy about links to relevant literature or any best practices.

Scaling, normalizing, transforming, is typically applied to variables, not observations, so this is what you refer to as scaling $(x_j)$ and $(y_j)$ separately.
However, scaling the outcome ($Y$) is not quite as common as scaling the input ($X$). For example, most procedures tend to distort the discrete nature of counts, which is usually undesirable. Transforming the outcome for predictive models also comes with its own issues, because any error in the outcome is transformed along with it (look up smearing retransformation, for example).$^\dagger$
Of course a non-linear transformation distorts the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, but this isn't necessarily a problem and can even be desirable:

If I want to model the effect of some drug concentration $X$ and expect the effect to plateau, a logarithmic transformation can incur such a plateau and I can interpret the results as the multiplicative effect of $X$ on $Y$.
A spline can be used specifically to model the non-linear relationship between $X$ and $Y$. This is essentially a specific combination of basis expansion and non-linear transformation of $X$.


$^\dagger$: Regression models typically assume $X$ is measured without error, which makes transformation less tricky.
